# Advance Search using Dropdown in Laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, laravel-5

I have a dropdown in dropdown four options are there and I'm trying to filter the data from database according to selected option, I have checked in console data is coming but in my view page data is not refreshing, I have attached image please check that, I'm Struggling please help.

This is my HTML Code view 
[right_side_bar latest image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1OdX.png)
                                                  [check this image for html view reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCwoP.png)

```
   <select id="property_id" name="property_type" onchange="property_type(this.value)">
        <option>Property Type</option>
        <option value="Single Family Home">Single Family Home</option>
        <option value="Multi_Family_Home">Multi Family Home</option>
        <option value="Condominium">Condominium</option>
        <option value="Townhome">Townhome</option>
   </select>
```

this is my right side code

```
          @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
               {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif  
      @foreach($row as $val)
    <div class="property-box">
        <div class="property-box-inner">

            <div class="property-box-picture">
                <div class="property-box-price">
                <a href="#">{{$val->state}}</a></div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target">
                    <img src="../images/test/{{$val->image}}" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="property-box-meta" id='basic-modal'>
                <div class="property-box-meta-item col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                    <strong>{{$val->property_room}}</strong>
                    <span>Bedroom</span>
            </div>

      <div class="property-box-meta-item col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                <strong>{{$val->property_baths}}</strong>
                <span>Bath</span>
            </div>

         <div class="property-box-meta-item col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                <strong>{{$val->property_size}}</strong>
                <span>Area</span>
            </div>
          <div class="property-box-meta-item col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                <strong>{{$val->property_baths}}</strong>
                <span>Garages</span>
            </div>
             <a href="{{ URL::to('pages/property_details', array('id'=>$val->id)) }}" class='basic'>More Details</a>

            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This my Controller Code to fetch the Data from Database

```
 public function property_type()
         {
          $term=Input::get('ptyname');
          $data = array();
          $display = DB::table('property_details')
                    ->where('property_type', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                    ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
                    ->get();
          var_dump($display);  
        if(count($display)!=0)
            {    
  return View::make('/pages/property_home', array('row'=>$display));
            }
            else
            {
            session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
    return View::make('/pages/property_home', array('row'=>$display));
            }
   }
```

This is My Ajax to load the controller

```
        <script>
       (function($) {
           $('#property_id').on('change', function() {
                var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                 var prop_type = optionSelected.val();
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "{{URL::to('/property_type') }}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: {ptyname: prop_type},
                   success:function(row)
                {

                     $('#getRequestdata').html(row.html);

                }
             }); 
         });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is my Routes

```
  Route::get('/property_type', array('as' => 'property_type', 'uses' => 'PageController@property_type'));
```

like this i am getting my data in console
     array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#293 (24) {
         ["id"]=>int(3)
         ["sale_or_rent"]=>string(4) "sale"
         ["property_type"]=>string(11) "Condominium"
         ["property_room"]=>string(1) "2"
         ["property_baths"]=> string(1) "2"
         ["property_size"]=>string(8) "200 sqft"
         ["property_garage"]=>string(1) "2"
         ["property_year"]=>string(4) "1959"
         ["property_floor"]=>string(1) "4"
         ["sale_by"]=>string(5) "owner"
         ["property_price"]=>string(7) "$200000"
         ["phonenumber"]=>string(10) "9941661138"
         ["address"]=>string(47) "610 Airport Rd, Nenana, AK 99760, United States"
         ["lat"]=>string(10) "64.5486956"
         ["log"]=>string(12) "-149.0927984"
         ["state"]=>string(6) "Alaska"
         ["city"]=>string(6) "Manely"
         ["zipcode"]=>string(6) "600097"
         ["description"]=>string(34) "this is my property ....contact me"
         ["image"]=>string(25) "2016-01-22-06-34-16-8.jpg"
         ["amenties"]=>string(63) "Air conditioning,Cleaning after exit,Dishwasher,Grill,Internet,"
         ["user_id"]=>string(0) ""
         ["created_at"]=>string(19) "2016-01-22 07:53:05"
         ["updated_at"]=>string(19) "2016-01-22 07:53:05"
        }
      }

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign response to your view, you should create some div where you would append/replace your response

eg: in your view, create div below your select drop down, like `<div id="search-response"> </div>`

```
<script>
   (function($) {
       $('#property_id').on('change', function() {
            var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
             var prop_type = optionSelected.val();
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "{{URL::to('pages/property_type') }}",
               dataType: "json",
               data: {ptyname: prop_type},
               success:function(row)
            {
                alert(val);
                //update your code by this
                // this will assign response to div
                //<div id="search-response"> </div>
                $("#search-response").html().html(row);
            }
         }); 
     });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanx for the reply ....according to my application when user searches any location then it redirect on map pages and shows result in map and right sidebar after that user want  to filter the property on the basis of property type , property price etc so my question is how i will remove the existing div and show filtered result in my view....

Comment: you can remove or set empty your div by class, id or tag eg `$('#id').remove();/empty()` or `$('.class').empty(); /remove();`

Comment: I have tried but it's not returning response to my view page but in console i am getting the result and when i'm using  $('.class').empty(); this code then div's are going permanently hidden...

Comment: `empty()` will remove your dom element contents, you have to assign it again, eg: you element class or id name is `ajax-content` so you can do this `$('#ajax-content').empty().html(row);` it will assign newly content to your div

Comment: I am getting the data in console but this error is coming ReferenceError: property_type is not defined    and where should i put this code  $('#ajax-content').empty().html(row); i have placed in my on that page but it's not returning any result in view part

Comment: can you share the code of your right side view ? means where you want to append ajax response

Comment: i have updated code for right side view please check that

Comment: can you tell me the line, where you want to show Ajax response data?

Comment: within foreach loop i want to load my data just check  @foreach($row as $val) starting and ending   @endforeach loop just check the line after starting of foreach loop  with in this class <div class="property-box">

Comment: I am supposing that you already generating your HTML from backend, and returning html in AJAX response, in your ajax function, where you wrote this `$("").html();` replace this line with this  `$('.property-box').empty('').html(row);` this will assign ajax response data into `property-box` div

Comment: can you show me your ajax response, show completely

Comment: I am asking about console response

Comment: suppose I am searching for a property through drop down  for that property two records are there in my database and i am getting response in my console like this

Comment: i have console data above check that i'm using var_dump() to check whether i am getting data or not..

Comment: sorry for the delay i am new to stack overflow that's why taking much time for formatting my code please suggest something....

Comment: comment out your `var_dump()` line, and add `->render();` with `View::make()` eg look this. `return View::make('/pages/property_home', array('row'=>$display))->render();` this will render/prepare your HTML for ajax response

Comment: can you tell me now what response you are getting ?

Comment: i am not getting anything but when i am using var_dump i can see the output in console response window and in html window i can see the results

Comment: its mean that you are getting the DB records, but not View HTML, just try something custom html and check in console. before `if()` statement write this eg: `return '<h1> Test me here </h1>';`

Comment: In my controller i have written your thing   return '<h1> Test me here </h1>'; but on view page it's not returning anything  i also have tried like this <div class="result"></div> and in ajax like this   $('.result').append(data);

Comment: http://localhost/realestate-site/public/property_type?ptyname=Condominium when i am opening the url in new tab  like this i can see the result

Comment: can you zip your files and send it to me ? So I can have a look?

Comment: you can attach here, just give me required files, not all

Comment: right now i'm leaving i will update my code after reaching my home

Comment: upload it somewhere else(some free storage area or google drive), and share the link here

Comment: check this link   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6ukGlAs8hDvTEZPUmxqcGtyWWM&usp=sharing

Comment: hey man in my controller i have tried like this                            $returnHTML = view('/pages/property_home')->with('row', $display)->render();
return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));      after that in my ajax i have tried to alert the value like this alert(row);   i am getting [object object] in my alert.

Comment: in your `alert` just type this `alert(row.html)` I hope you will get the response

Comment: Hi I'm getting the result but it's not returning in correct format, I'm getting my whole webpage with results but i'm only want results not whole web page, so how i can send only html view of filtered things... and thanxx for your reply

Comment: actually you are returning overall view `view('/pages/property_home')` So you have to return specific view, eg copy your right side content area, and create a new view `rightsidearea.blade.php` and paste it in it. save it, and now in your controller method, do this  `view('/pages/rightsidearea')....` you will get specific result

Comment: Hi i'am sorry need one more help ....onchange I'm getting the results from DB but old record is not going, idea is to remove the old record's and show filtered results.     thanxx

Comment: which old record you want to remove ? still that right sidebar one ?

Comment: yes,  On homepage one searchbox is there when user is searching any city/state according to that i'm showing the results on nextpage in right sidebar  after that user can filter the data usnig advance search but when i'm filtering old record is not going whatever record i had got from homepage search.

Comment: can you show me your latest ajax code, which you are using to send request and update results ?

Comment: also share your right side html structure, and where is this element `getRequestdata`?  actually you have to set empty your old results 1st then you have to assign new results. eg if your old results exists in this div `getRequestdata` then you have to do this `$('#getRequestdata').html('').html(row.html)`

Comment: thanx man now it's working before that i was not returning the output in that div

Comment: Hi thanx man my query is when user selects a dropdown ,i want to load both the things at the same time in google map with filtered result and right side content.Now right side filtering is working fine

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct one, and create a new question for your this problem, with screen shots and details. So I will answer it there. actually these comments getting too long, so avoid this. and create new one

Comment: I have already marked your question as correct, I think my reputaion is below 15 that's why it;s not showing  here is my thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837349/on-change-load-google-map-and-div-from-database-laravel5